# On Click of Mouse opens multiple windows (for example multiple file explorer or terminal windows)

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop, raspberry-pi-imager

I am facing  a issue where my mouse click is not working and it opens multiple windows .

Point 1 :
When I start my raspberry pi I see below in my home screen which did not appear before .

[image]

Now when I open a file explorer  and as soon as I click my mouse a new file explorer windows opens ,as soon I click a mouse anywhere on the screen a new file explorer opens up like below .So if I do 100 clicks anywhere on screen 100 window opens up . Can some one plz help if there is anything wrong with my raspberry pi . It was working fine till yesterday .

[image]

Comment: it is not `pie`

Comment: sounds like a stuck down key on keyboard

Comment: @jsotola You are right , it was silly keyboard key which got stuck down . Sorry for my stupid question . I just panicked as I recently got my pi and as it stopped working after I did some experiments I just got nervous . Can you please add your comment as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: it is not a question about Raspberry Pi ... it is a linux desktop manager question ... it is off topic here, so an answer is also off topic hete

Comment: Please clarify what HW and SW you are using. Raspberry Pi Desktop is a version for PC/MAC, not for the Pi hardware, do you really use that? Have you  changed any settings after the installation?